# changing the button text from the edittext state

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have one button and 1 edittext. The button is set to "change", and EditText is enable-false. When you click on a button, its text is changed to "save", and edit text is available for input. After a second press, the text changes to "change" again, and the button becomes Enable-false.

how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this onClickListener on your button -

```
Button yourButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button)
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext)

      yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!yourEdittext.isEnabled()){
                yourButton.setText("Save");
                yourEditText.setEnabled(true);
                counter++;
            }else if (yourEdittext.isEnabled()){
                yourButton.setText("Change again");
                yourButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Make sure to set the initial button's text and the edit text disabled for the starting point

Comment: can I ask you about another problem?

Comment: Sure,  but if it's a full grown-up question it's best you post it as a question and give me here a link to it :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821724/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Do you have it in English?

Comment: "
I have 2 activities with TextView, which using requestCode and resultCode pass integers to the TextView of the main activity. When I alternately enter the numbers in the activity, their result replaces each other in the main activity. How to make so that in AllFace.setText the sum with these two activity was written down."

Comment: "
The code I sent is working the way it should. I just do not know how to combine the 1 result of 2 intenta. Variables face_661_1 and face_661_2 can not be thrown over the cases"